# Cron job approach for reminder script

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a php script that's similar to a reminder/todo application. Users schedule their alerts and the script emails them accordingly.

I'm newly introduced to cron jobs and not versed in how it works. Please advise me how to do this. Reminders can be set at any time by the user in a 24 hour period. Assuming that my script can run only 30 seconds will I have to send cron jobs every 30 seconds to check if anyone is scheduled for an email? Will that be overkill?

Comment: 1. check db every minute, or 2. run a php daemon.There are hosting issues for both of theses, most shared hosts would not allow 2, and most restrict 1 also.

Comment: @Dagon, thanks! would increasing the time limit for php script also help? Also, is php daemon like cron job?

Comment: i don't see why you would increase the time limit for the script. By default scripts called by the command line (and cron) have no time limit anyway.  A daemon is program that is away running.

Comment: @Dagon I'm under the impression that any php script runs 30 seconds. The command line executes the script but it ends after 30 seconds, no? It checks any scheduled entries for 30 seconds. This is why I would increase time limit in php and use cron to keep executing the script.

Comment: no. max_execution_time = 0 (unlimited) for CLI. And your call via cron does not "checks any scheduled entries for 30 seconds". You check the db once and run what's required. How long it takes to run depends on how many emails you need to send.